# hg:command not found

Tags: mercurial

I am trying to clone a repository from bitbucket, and I installed mercurial, and copied the HTTPS command. When I run this command I still get hg: command not found, why is this?

Comment: How did you install mercurial? Did however you install it make sure that it was installed in a location which is included in your `PATH`?

Comment: Why did you tag your question with `git` ? `git` and `mercurial` are rather mutually exclusive.

Comment: You need to tell us exactly the command you're trying to execute, rather than just saying "this command".

Comment: What distribution, please? And how did you install mercurial? For preference use your distribution's binary package.

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial was not installed correctly. I used easy_install and it worked correctly, rather than apt-get.